# Convert SELECT statment MySQL to Function PL/SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

I have SELECT `statment`in `MySQL` which I need to transfer to function in Oracle `PL/SQL`
Currently when I test Query in `MYSQL Workbench` it return one value, but when I run it in SQLDeveloper I get totally wrong data or worst case I didnt get anythink.

```
 $sql =  SELECT
                p.ProjectID,
                p.CustomName,
                p.Name,
                p.Responsible_person_id,
                p.Delivery_contact,
                p.StartDate,
                p.EndDate,
                p.TehnicReview,
                p.status
                FROM
                    projects p
                LEFT JOIN
                    project_users_schedule_dates pusd
                ON
                    pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND 
                    pusd.UserID = $currentUserId
                LEFT JOIN 
                    responsible_persons rp
                ON 
                    rp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND 
                    rp.UserID = $currentUserId
                LEFT JOIN 
                    users u
                ON 
                    u.UserID = $currentUserId
                WHERE
                    u.User_roleID = 1
                OR 
                (
                        (p.Responsible_person_id = $currentUserId OR 
                         p.Delivery_contact = $currentUserId OR 
                         rp.UserID = $currentUserId OR 
                         (pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND                         
                            pusd.UserID = $currentUserId AND NOW() BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                    AND
                        NOW() BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                    AND p.status = 2
                    )

                )
                GROUP BY 
                    p.ProjectID
                ORDER BY 
                    p.ProjectID
                LIMIT 
                    $limit OFFSET $offset";
```

And here is my PL/SQL function

```
create or replace FUNCTION GETALLPROJECTS(currentUserId IN INT)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
              OPEN rc FOR
              SELECT
                p.ProjectID,
                p.CustomName,
                p.Name,
                p.Responsible_person_id,
                p.Delivery_contact,
                p.StartDate,
                p.EndDate,
                p.TehnicReview,
                p.status
                FROM
                    projects p
                LEFT JOIN
                    project_users_schedule_dates pusd
                ON
                    pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND 
                    pusd.UserID = currentUserId
                LEFT JOIN 
                    responsible_persons rp
                ON 
                    rp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND 
                    rp.UserID = currentUserId
                LEFT JOIN 
                    users u
                ON 
                    u.UserID = currentUserId
                WHERE
                    u.User_roleID = 1
                OR 
                (
                        (p.Responsible_person_id = currentUserId OR 
                         p.Delivery_contact = currentUserId OR 
                         rp.UserID = currentUserId OR 
                         (pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND                         
                          pusd.UserID = currentUserId AND sysdate BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + SYSDATE + 1 
                    AND
                        sysdate BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate + SYSDATE + 1)
                    AND p.status = 2
                    )
                )                 
                GROUP BY 
                    p.ProjectID;
                
                ORDER BY 
                    p.ProjectID;
  RETURN rc;
END GETALLPROJECTS;
```

Function needs to return Name,CustoName,ProjectID etc base on `Id`
When I run this code I get empty result.

[image]

I assume the error could be in return type but not sure 100%

Comment: Make sure that query itself returns result; then move it into a function. These parts look wrong: `p.EndDate + SYSDATE + 1` - if `EndDate`'s datatype is DATE, you can't add another date (which SYSDATE is) to it.

Comment: `(pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND                         
                            pusd.UserID = $currentUserId AND NOW() BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                    AND
                        NOW() BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: This part I get it from here, and I belive this shouldn't be any error. Or I just gues:)

Comment: That's just `p.EndDate + 1` in Oracle. When adding *numbers* to *dates*, you add "number of days" to it. Or, if you insist, `p.EndDate + interval '1' day`.

Comment: Seems like the MySQL version has a `LIMIT` clause but there's no equivalent `fetch first` clause in the Oracle one.