# How to write DateTime stamp to PLSQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

```
NOW() BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

I want to write this query to PL/SQL format.
When I write something like following doesn't work

```
(SYSDATE BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + SYSDATE + 1)) a
```

And this also doesn't work

```
(SYSDATE BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + 1)) a
```

Comment: This seems like duplicate question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339003/convert-select-statment-mysql-to-function-pl-sql. With exact same query parts, even aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does "does not work" mean? Sample data would help.

Anyway: these *should* work if those "date" columns are DATE datatype.

```
sysdate between startDate and EndDate + 1
```

or

```
sysdate between startDate and EndDate + interval '1' day
```

Note that DATE contains both DATE and TIME component, so you might need to use e.g. `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`. As I said: sample data would help.